# YAML: Order Output from Dictionary

Tags: python, yaml

I'd like to write the following output to a YAML file:

```
'0':[]
'1':[]
'2':[]
'3':[]
...
'100':[]
```

I can do this:

```
import yaml
d = {str(i):[] for i in range(101)}
with open('result.yml', 'w') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(d, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False)
```

But the order won't be preserved.  How can I get that desired output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

YAML defines that the order of mapping keys must not convey content information. Therefore, you must not depend on the order of mapping keys when you're using YAML. See also [this discussion](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/110). If what you're doing depends on the order of keys, you should use a list, e.g.:

```
import yaml

d = [{str(i): []} for i in range(101)]
with open('result.yml', 'w') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(d, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False)
```

Which gives you:

```
- '0': []
- '1': []
- '2': []
```

With the order of keys preserved because you wrapped the key-value pairs in a list.

If you really need to write the mapping as it is with the order you want it to have, you can still use the low-level event API:

```
import yaml
from yaml.events import *

d = [StreamStartEvent(), DocumentStartEvent(),
     MappingStartEvent(anchor=None, tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', implicit=True)]
for i in range(101):
  d.extend([ScalarEvent(anchor=None, tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', value=str(i),
                       implicit=(True, True)),
            SequenceStartEvent(anchor=None, tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:seq', implicit=True),
            SequenceEndEvent()])
d.extend([MappingEndEvent(), DocumentEndEvent(), StreamEndEvent()])

with open('result.yml', 'w') as yaml_file:
  yaml.emit(d, yaml_file)
```